# MySQL/MariaDB recursive statement, Return empty if children do not match condition

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, recursive-query

I have tables like this in the database:

Category

| id_category | id_parent | level_depth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 20 | 2 | 2 |
| 21 | 2 | 2 |
| 22 | 2 | 2 |
| 30 | 22 | 3 |

category_product

| id_category | id_product |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 200 |
| 2 | 201 |
| 2 | 202 |
| 20 | 202 |
| 20 | 203 |
| 20 | 204 |

I have this statement that deletes the categories that have no products.

```
Db::getInstance()->execute('UPDATE '._DB_PREFIX_.'category SET `active` = 0 WHERE `id_category` NOT IN(SELECT `id_category` FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product)');
```

But this doesn't work for me because I don't want to delete parent categories if the child categories do have products.
**I would like to get the categories that have no products where all of their children also have no products.**

I've been experimenting with recursive select statements, but I would need it to return nothing in case any children have a product. **This query is not correct** because it returns all the categories that do not have any product and also all the children that do not have a product.

```
with recursive decendents as (
-- Category that has no Products
Select c.id_category
FROM category c
WHERE c.id_category NOT IN(SELECT id_category
FROM category_product)
join all
-- child categories
    SELECT c.id_category
FROM category c, descendants d
WHERE c.id_parent = d.id_category AND c.id_category NOT IN(SELECT id_category
FROM category_product)
)
SELECT id_category From descendants
```

Any idea how I can get this? either with recursive query or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Show desired final data state

Comment: I want to get the categories whose child categories do not have products.  In case any child category contains a product - Return nothing. If not, return category tree. category_id

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can write update statement as follows

```
UPDATE category c JOIN category_product cp ON cp.`id_category` = c.`id_category` SET c.`active` = 0
```

and if your execute it from a tool make sure

> sql_safe_updates
> set o

as we are updating with out primary key

Comment: Ok, thank you, but at the same time, I want to check if the child categories have product or not. I can't deactivate parent categories if some child category contains product's.

Comment: inner join return the rows only when primary key exists in both the tables and if we want we can add where condition at end as doule check